# Jquery/JS: Call a function of Jquery-function outside Jquery-function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

```
(function($){
    $.fn.the_func = function() {

        function my_func(){
            alert('it works');
        }

        my_func();

        // other code

    };
})(jQuery);

$(window).load(function(){
    my_func(); // This way?
    $.the_func().my_func(); // Or this way? No?
    $.the_func.my_func(); // No?
    // ?
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').the_func();
});
```

How can I call this function outside the function which wraps it?
I want to call `my_func()` like in this code-example.
(the window-load function is just an example.)
I want to call `my_func()` from "everywhere" without executing other functions or code within `the_func()`. BUT I want to use the variables of `the_func()`.
With `my_func()` I want to update values which are stored in parameters of `the_func()`.

Comment: How about calling it like `$("div").the_func("my_func")`? Would that work? I don't mean with your current solution...I mean if you would be okay with that syntax, because that's the way I know hot to structure it to make it work as you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of how I usually write a plugin and could applied to your situation:

http://jsfiddle.net/pMPum/1/

```
(function ($) {
    function my_func(element) {
        console.log("it works: " + element.innerHTML);
    }

    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            console.log("from init");
            console.log("options for init: " + JSON.stringify(options));
            my_func(this);
        },

        my_func: function (options) {
            console.log("from my_func");
            console.log("options for my_func: " + JSON.stringify(options));
            my_func(this);
        }
    };

    $.fn.the_func = function (method) {
        var args = arguments;
        var argss = Array.prototype.slice.call(args, 1);

        return this.each(function () {
            if (methods[method]) {
                methods[method].apply(this, argss);
            }
            else if (typeof method === "object" || !method) {
                methods.init.apply(this, args);
            }
            else {
                $.error("Method " + method + " does not exist on jQuery.the_func");
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div").the_func({    // Same as passing "init" and { } as params
        test: "testing"
    });
});
```

Notice how I made a generic `my_func` function inside the scope that can be called. The `my_func` method in `methods` is what is exposed to the world through the plugin syntax `.the_func()` and the `my_func` function is private and inaccessible directly.

The syntax for calling different methods is the same as most/plenty jQuery plugins.

Comment: thx. but how do i call "my_func" inside the "init"-function? ..why do you use "return this.each(func…)"?

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith Just updated my answer. And I use `return this.each` so that chaining may occur with the jQuery plugin call. So you could do something like `$("div").the_func("method").addClass("something").show();` - it makes it so after the `the_func` call, any jQuery methods are applied to the original selector